# Parameters passed from angular 7 to my Asp.net core WebApi controller are all null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular7, asp.net-core-routing

I have this code below and I want to pass two parameters from Angular 7 app to my Asp.Net Core WebApi controller, I just don't know the syntax for the Angular http post call to the controller. The controller is getting all null values when it's hit. But I can pass in a model it works just fine!

Question - here is what I don't understand. When I pass in a model like this

```cs
[HttpPost("confirm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(EmailConfirmationOptions options) {}
```

and have my post pass in a model as well, like this. It works!

```cs
const model = {UserId: userId, Code: code };
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'confirm', model);
```

Here is my Angular call where I've tried different values but none seem to pass them correctly.

```cs
confirm(userId: number, code: string) {
    // return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'confirm, { userId, code });
    // return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'confirm/' + userId + '/code/' + code, {});
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'confirm', userId);
}
```

Here is my controller, where userId comes in as 0 and code comes in a null

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
//[HttpPost("confirm")]
//[HttpPost("{id}/{code}", Name = "confirm")]
// [HttpPost("{userId}", Name = "confirm")]
[HttpPost("confirm")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code) 
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("error");
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    if (user == null) {
        return BadRequest("error");
    }

    // code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);

    if (result.Succeeded) {
        return Ok();
    } else {
        return BadRequest("error");
    } 
}
```

Comment: did you try using a REST client ? postman or similiar

Comment: It is not professional way to send parameters in route rather than sending it as object..if you append values in routes there might be security tampering issues will occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client side request looks like this

```js
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'confirm/' + userId + '/code/' + code, {});
```

The route template on the server would need to match the intended route

```cs
[HttpPost("confirm/{userId}/code/{code}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code) {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

If the controller has the `[ApiController]` attribute, then try to be explicit about where the data is to be bound from

```cs
[HttpPost("confirm/{userId}/code/{code}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail([FromRoute]string userId, [FromRoute]string code) {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)